# Wordpress rest api cat 1 and cat 2

Tags: wordpress, rest, api

I am using Wordpress rest api to query category id’s like so:

http://localhost:8888/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?type=press_release&per_page=4&categories=15,25

Which returns results in either cat 15 OR 25

I need to only return results if they are in cat 15 AND 25.

Done loads of searching and cannot find a solution to this.

Anyone know if this can be done and how?

Thank, Jamie

Answer (score 0):

swap `,` with `+`

`&categories=15+25`

UPDATE:

actually, this doesn't seem to work as you'd expect https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/41287

if the above does not work, you'll have to create a custom endpoint with `register_rest_route` with a callback function and return the posts with a new `WP_Query` using the `category__and` parameter